# How to better transfer objects between Jersey restful enabled classes to JSP pages

Tags: web-services, jsp, jersey

I have this :

```
public class Base {

    @GET
    @Path("/news/{page_number}")
    public Viewable news(@PathParam("page_number") int pageNumber) {

        NewsParams news_params = new NewsParams();
        news_params.setPageNumber(pageNumber);

        return new Viewable("/news.jsp", news_params);
    }
}
```

and the news.jsp is :

```
   ${it.pageNumber}
```

My question is : What to do (or which is the best way) if a have a lot of objects to transfer from jersey restful classes (which represent the application logic) to the JSP pages (which represent the application view) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a POJO to the Viewable instead.  If you were to pass a Customer object with an Address property then you could access the date in your JSP as follows:

```
${it.firstName}
${it.lastName}
${it.address.street}
${it.address.city}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to pass a POJO to the Viewable and use as shown by Doughan above. In addition to that you could also pass around request attributes or via session, though personally I always try to avoid session wherever and whenever possible.

Example of passing request attributes can be found [here](https://github.com/imyousuf/smart-user/blob/master/smart-user-resource/src/main/java/com/smartitengineering/user/ws/resources/OrganizationsResource.java),
Line 56, 57 and 103 will comprise of the example.